# code hangs when running interactive shell using paramiko

Tags: python, paramiko

I have written below code to run 3 command in remote server interactively

But when I checked 3rd command never executed and code stuck here is my code

```
def execute():
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect('ipaddress', username='user', password='pw')

    chan = ssh.invoke_shell()  # start the shell before sending commands

    chan.send('cd /path to folder/test')
    chan.send('\n')
    time.sleep(3)
    chan.send("ls -l")
    chan.send('\n')
    buff = ''
    while not buff.endswith("test >"):
        resp = chan.recv(9999)
        # code stuck here after 'path to folder/test >' comes in shell prompt
        buff += resp
        print resp

    print "test"
    chan.send("ls -lh")
    chan.send('\n')
    time.sleep(5)
    buff = ''
    while not buff.endswith("test >"):
        resp = chan.recv(9999)
        buff += resp
        print resp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    execute()
```

When I ran I got output of `ls -l` but `ls -lh` never executed my code stuck in first while loop. Anyone please help to resolve my issue

Comment: as far as i can see, you don't actually need to launch a shell, knowing some security issue if you use shell directly. have you tried `exec_command` in client class?

Comment: i haven't tried i thought for interactive command execution in shell invoke_shell is the right api

Comment: no it's not. you should try exec_command as it returns all 3 channels to you.

Comment: i have used invoke_shell because i need to execute sequence of command one after other from particular folder that's why if i used execute_command then channel was closed after executing 1st command

Comment: so can `exec_command`. you should read documentation.

Comment: as doc said When the command finishes executing, the channel will be closed and can’t be reused. You must open a new channel if you wish to execute another command.

Comment: you will be calling `exec_command` multiple times. what's your goal? you should just use `stdout` and wait for execution termination.

Answer (score 1):

The code has following 2 errors:

- The call to `channel.recv` is blocking, you should first check if channel has any data to be read or not using `channel.recv_ready()`
- Also don't use  `buff.endswith("test >")` as a condition.As
  the file_name might not always be at the last in buff.

Change the while block to following and it will run the way you want

```
    while "test >" not in buff:
        if chan.recv_ready():
            resp = chan.recv(9999)    
            # code won't stuck here
            buff+=resp
            print resp
```

Answer (score 0):

Unable to leave a comment, but @divyam jaiswal had a great solution!

Here's the Python 3 version:

```
while "test >" not in buff:
    if chan.recv_ready():
        resp = chan.recv(9999).decode("utf-8")   
        # code won't get stuck here
        buff += resp
        print(resp)
```